# Why does print strtotime('2020-11-02') - strtotime('2020-11-01'); return 90,000 seconds?

Tags: php, strtotime

print strtotime('2020-01-02') - strtotime('2020-01-01'); returns 86,400
print strtotime('2020-02-02') - strtotime('2020-02-01'); returns 86,400
etc.
print strtotime('2020-11-02') - strtotime('2020-11-01'); return 90,000 seconds

My apologies if this has been asked before.  I checked and didn't find anything.

My program is calculating the days between two dates, counting the first date as one.
Here is a sample I'm working with:

```
<?php
function dateDifference($d1, $d2)
{
    // calulating the difference in days 
    // get seconds between dates
    $diff = strtotime($d2) - strtotime($d1);
    // 1 day = 24 hours 
    // 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds
    // '2020-11-02' and '2020-11-01' returns three days.
    return ceil(abs($diff / 86400))+1;// Start day is day one.
}
    $d1 = '2020-11-01';
    $d2 = '2020-11-02';
    $trip_days = dateDifference($d1,$d2);
    // returns three days, not two.
    echo 'Total Days between 11/01/2020 and 11/02/2020: ' . $trip_days . "\n";
    $d1 = '2020-10-01';
    $d2 = '2020-10-02';
    $trip_days = dateDifference($d1,$d2);
    echo 'Total Days between 10/01/2020 and 10/02/2020: ' . $trip_days . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe some setting on your system as I get 86400.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Bc7Jj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This year, daylight saving's ended on Sunday November 1st.

We got an extra hour which is 3,600 seconds,

```
86,400 + 3,600 = 90,000
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a daylight savings time issue.

Some places, like Canada and some US states, changed from daylight savings time to standard/winter time on Sunday 1st of November 2020, making the clock jump from 02:00 back to 01:00. Therefore, you got an extra hour that night.

Source: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html